# Finding all other roots of complex equation knowing the solution.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_1 = 3 + 2i$ be a solution of the following equation. Use this information to find all other (complex or real) roots of $$p(z) = z^4 - 6z^3 + 15z^2 -12z +26$$
Please, help me understand how to solve this type of problem, it will be perfect if you will send me the solution, so I could analyze it for myself. Thanks.

This is what I obtained:

$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}  \color\green{\text{Zeros: }} & \color\green{3 + 2i} & \color\green{3 - 2i} \\ \\ \hline & z^4 & z^3 & z^2 & z^1 & z^0 \\
& 1 & -6 & 15 & -12 & 26 \\
\color\red{3 + 2i} & \downarrow & 3 + 2i & -13 & 6 + 4i & -26\\
\hline
& 1 & -3 + 2i & 2 & -6 + 4i & |\phantom{-}0 \\
\color\red{3 - 2i} & \downarrow & 3 - 2i & 0 & 6 - 4i & |\phantom{-}0\\
\hline
& 1 & 0 & 2 & |\phantom{-} 0 & |\phantom{-} 0
\end{array}$$

$$\therefore \frac{p(z)}{(z - 3 - 2i)(z - 3 + 2i)} = z^2 + 2$$

Comment: What have tried? Show your attempts.

Comment: I don't know how to approach this equation

Comment: just divide the polynomial by $(3+2i)$, you'd get another polynomial $q(x)$ of less degree, in this case degree $3$, then you solve for this new polynomial by guessing one of its root, and then again divide $q(x)$ with it.

Comment: @AndriiDovhun show your progress, because it seems like you just want somebody do your homework

Comment: Edit your question including your efforts. you can get a solution.

Comment: Since the polynomial is real, you also have $3 - 2i$ as a root.

Comment: guys, can you check what i've done

Comment: @DanielMuñoz i added photo of my solution

Comment: @AndriiDovhun post it here ...

Comment: @DanielMuñoz i edited my post and added link to imgur

Comment: @LionHeart i added link to my solution

Comment: @AndriiDovhun Your solution works, but it would be easier to just use [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). Suppose the other two roots are $a,b$ then $a + b + (3+2i)+(3-2i)=6$
and $a b (3+2i)(3-2i)=26$ so $\ldots$

Comment: @AndriiDovhun nice, now solve $x^2+2=0$ and you would have all the solutions :)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684391/knowing-a-solution-of-the-complex-equation-z-1-32i-find-other-roots-of-px?noredirect=1#comment9907242_4684391)

Comment: @TymaGaidash so what, that question was closed for some reason, but I didn't get the solution. Now I understand, thnks everybody.